# jQuery, how a variable can keep the same value?

Tags: jquery, variables

I define a jQuery varible like this:

```
var $test = $('#myblock').height();
```

Now lets say the height of #myblock is changing when the mouse is above it, then the value of $test is also changing. How can force $test to keep its first value?

Comment: it won't change unless you reassign the value to the variable again

Comment: just set variable in outer scope than mouse event handler, not set it inside handler

Comment: Only certain objects are live, such as nodeLists, assigning a height to a variable does not change the variable as the height changes, it stays whatever it was at the time you assigned it.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse no , once you assing a value to a variable it will never change , unless you assign this value once more.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is standard behavior. When you assign `$test` a value, that value will not change unless you assign it another value. This is true even if `#myblock`'s height changes after the first assignment.